# Zend Framework: How do I set a custom validator on a form element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I'm writing a custom validator that checks that at least one field has a value. I want to validate that either 'namefield' or 'idfield' has a value. One of them can be empty, or both can have a value, but at least one of them must have a value.

```
$nameField = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('namefield');
$nameField->setValue($this->nameFieldValue)
          ->addValidator('AtLeastOneHasValue', false, array('idfield'));
```

From what I understand, my validator will not validate unless I set my form element to required.

```
->setRequired(true)
```

But if I set it to required, it automatically validates that it is not empty, and the error message says that it is empty. I want to allow the field to be empty, and validate multiple fields with my custom validator. How do I validate a form element with my custom validator, without setting the form element to required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this documentation page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html) for the setAllowEmpty() method. This should help you get where you are trying to go.

> setAllowEmpty($flag) and
>   getAllowEmpty() allow you to modify
>   the behaviour of optional elements
>   (i.e., elements where the required
>   flag is false). When the 'allow empty'
>   flag is true, empty values will not be
>   passed to the validator chain.

Comment: ->setAllowEmpty(false)
This was just what I needed. Thanks!